# Shoutcast Streaming & HTML5 Audio Player

Tags: html, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio, shoutcast

This is really driving me crazy

I am trying t make audio tag stream a shoutcast stream

I am shooting on this since two days and the best result I got is making it working on Safari

I read all the questions on stackoverflow about this I read all the tutorials I tested all the players and I need to make it work on Mobile phones and specifically on iOS so I can't use flash tried a lot

```
<audio controls src="http://a7lafm.callu.ps:8000/;" autoplay></audio>
```

This snippet works on Safari ONLY

I tried the **`;`** semicolon and `stream.ogg` 
I think I tried everything so I am posting the question here

Any help are really appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with your code.  There are two problems.

The first is browser codec support.  Check out the [MDN page for updated info on codec support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) per browser.

The second problem is that SHOUTcast returns an oddball status line.  It will send `ICY 200 OK` instead of `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`.  Some browsers will not accept this header.  The only way around it is to use something else for your streaming server, such as [Icecast](http://icecast.org/).  (If you're interested, I also run a streaming service that can relay your existing SHOUTcast stream in a standards-compliant HTTP stream that has better compatibility.  E-mail preview@audiopump.co if you are interested.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I found on a shoutcast radio station website:

```
<audio autoplay preload="auto" controls src="http://174.137.50.51:16504/;"></audio>
```

Works fine in various browsers. I tested Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: The problem is *mostly* specific to Internet Explorer, which you did not test in, and certain versions of Firefox.

Comment: No, the question doesn't mention IE:"... I need to make it work on Mobile phones and specifically on iOS..."

Comment: The `/;` in the end of the `src` attribute is the game changer!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--listen2myradio.com SHOUTcast Flash Player-->
    <p id='preview'></p><script id='myscript' language='javascript' src='http://flashplayer.listen2myradio.com/getInfo.js?id=17733c2862180eaa3883250ab04087609ae4'></script>
    <!--End Player-->
```

This is your radio and where we pray every time we enter the Internet open and a window to the .Flm